# Write PPM file header

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I am trying to write a PPM file and am having trouble with the header specifically.

I have a function taking in a file pointer and header struct containing my header information.

```
void writeHeader(FILE* file, struct Header* header){
    char space[] = " ";
    char newLine[] = "\n";

    fwrite(&header->magicNum[0], sizeof(char), 1, file);
    fwrite(&header->magicNum[1], sizeof(char), 1, file);
    fwrite(newLine, sizeof(char), 1, file);

    fwrite(&(header->width), sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fwrite(space, sizeof(char), 1, file);
    fwrite(&header->height, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fwrite(newLine, sizeof(char), 1, file);

    fwrite(&header->maxColor, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fwrite(newLine, sizeof(char), 1, file);
    fwrite(space, sizeof(char), 1, file);
}
```

When I call this I end up only writing the first two values "P6" to file and then blanks after (or dots in hex editor). I have also tried removing the space and newline characters but I still don't get anything after P6. How can I write the rest of my header to file along with the necessary space and newline characters where needed?

Comment: are the rest of the header struct fields initialized? did you fflush the data?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `fwrite()` instead of `fprintf()`?

Comment: All fields are initialized, open to using any writing function this was just the one I seemed to be having the most luck with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the PPM header is stored in ascii strings, I would say something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OUTFILE "file.ppm"

struct Header {
    char magicNum[3];
    int width;
    int height;
    int maxColor;
};

void writeHeader(FILE* file, struct Header* header)
{
    fprintf(file, "%s\n", header->magicNum);
    fprintf(file, "%d %d\n", header->width, header->height);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", header->maxColor);
}

int main()
{
    struct Header header;
    FILE *fp;

    strcpy(header.magicNum, "P6");
    header.width = 1920;
    header.height = 1080;
    header.maxColor = 255;

    fp = fopen(OUTFILE, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(OUTFILE);
        exit(1);
    }
    writeHeader(fp, &header);

    // write the ppm data to the file

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the PPM header example [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#Description), you will see that the width and height numbers are stored as ASCII text in the file (similar to how you correctly stored the number 6 in "P6" as text).

But in the code that follows, you appear to be writing actual integers (for width and height, etc) from memory to the file, which depends on your system's architecture and is not the same as writing the ASCII characters that represent the integers. Here I have annotated a hexdump from my system (with an "image" of width 5, height 4, maxColor 3), where my integers are stored across 4 bytes with the least-significant byte first:

```
(ch = character; sp = space)
          ch ch ch --integer-- ch  --integer-- ch --intege
          P  6  \n |width:5--| sp  |height:4-| \n |maxCol:
00000000  50 36 0a 05 00 00 00 20  04 00 00 00 0a 03 00 00  |P6..... ........|
00000010  00 0a 20                                          |.. |
          3| \n sp
          r- ch ch
```

So programmatically your code seems to work, but I don't think it is achieving what you intend.

This is probably what you want to end up with:

```
          ch ch ch ch ch ch ch ch  ch ch
          P  6  \n 5  sp 4  \n 3   \n sp
00000000  50 36 0a 35 20 34 0a 33  0a 20                    |P6.5 4.3. |
```

Comment: So are you saying I need to convert my ints to chars before writing them?

Comment: @user2355903 Yes. After you do that, you should see the rest of the header values appearing as text when you do the hexdump. Note that if you are using the P6 format, you probably will end up writing actual number values (non-text) to the file later for the pixel data.

Comment: @user2355903 To clarify: I'm saying you need to convert your numbers into strings before writing. If you just change the data type of the numbers from "integer" to "char" and still try to write them as numbers, that will not fix the issue.